# Create a new album in the gallery and save images to it

Tags: android, save, gallery, media

I have been looking everywhere but cannot figure out how to create an album in the gallery and save images to it.
Can someone please help me? 
The only thing i have managed to do is this code that only saves the image in the gallery:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bm, "A" , "B");
```

Thanks for your help !